# Left join query to fetch data from database but double results

Tags: mysql

I have this code i use to fetch data from a database. it should show all the articles from the database and for every article i need to show all the images per that article (and i don't know how many photos are stored in the database) and then output the result but it double the item that it shows:

```
function show_volanti($data){

    $con = $data;                                                   // PASSO CONNESSIONE
    $id = 1;                                                        // 1 VOLANTE
    $visibile = 1;                                                  // VARIABILE DI VISIBILITA'

    $rows = array();                                                // PREPARO ARRAY 1 PER ID ARTICOLI VOLANTE

    $g = '';                                                        // RIFERIMENTO ASSOCIAZIONE GALLERY VIEWER
    //$rif_id = '';                                                 // RIF_ID SE OK DA CANCELLARE

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);                                 // INIZIALIZZO LA CONNESSIONE

    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,'SELECT articoli.id AS id_articoli,
                                      articoli.titolo,
                                      articoli.descrizione,
                                      galleria.id AS id_galleria,
                                      galleria.foto,
                                      galleria.rif_id
                                      FROM articoli
                                      LEFT JOIN galleria
                                      ON articoli.id = galleria.rif_id
                                      WHERE articoli.genere1 = ?
                                      AND articoli.visibile = ?')
                                      or mysqli_error($stmt);                                   // QUERY INSERIMENTO DATI

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'ii',$id,$visibile);                                           // LEGO I PARAMETRI

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);                                                                 // ESEGUO LA QUERY

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,
                            $rows['id_articoli'],
                            $rows['titolo'],
                            $rows['descrizione'],
                            $rows['id_galleria'],
                            $rows['foto'],
                            $rows['rif_id']);

    // CREO RIFERIMENTO PER GALLERIA NEL VIEWER

    $html = "";
    $html .= "<div class='container'>";

    $html .= "  <div class='row'>";
    $html .= "    <div class='col-sm-12'>";
    $html .= "      <div class='panel panel-default'>";
    $html .= "        <div class='panel-body'>";    

    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){

        $html .= " <div class='panel panel-default'>";
        $html .= " <div class='panel-heading'><b>$rows[titolo]</b></div>";
        $html .= " <div class='panel-body'><div class='class_p'>$rows[descrizione]</div></div>";
        $html .= "</div>";
    }



    $html .= "        </div> <!-- end panel-body -->";
    $html .= "      </div> <!-- end panel panel-default -->";
    $html .= "    </div> <!-- end col-sm-12 -->";

    $html .= "  </div> <!-- end row -->";   

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);                                       // CHIUDO LO STATEMENT
    mysqli_close($con);                                             // CHIUDO CONNESSIONE   

    return $html;
}
```

with a single query like this one, i have the right results so it is a left join problem. I am doing it in the wrong way:

```
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,'SELECT articoli.id AS id_articoli,
                                  articoli.titolo,
                                  articoli.descrizione
                                  FROM articoli
                                  WHERE articoli.genere1 = ?
                                  AND articoli.visibile = ?')
                                  or mysqli_error($stmt);                                   // QUERY INSERIMENTO DATI
```

Comment: The problem is with data, galleria table have multiple rif_id which is matching with single id of articoli.id. That's why it's duplicating

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply. Yes in the table galleria i have lots of images that are related to the same article in table articoli.. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: anyone who can help me please?